# Is it possible to change some code in YOLO object detection (GPU Version)?

Tags: c++, deep-learning, yolo

I working on an object detection project in these days but I got stuck in changing some code of **YOLOV3 GPU version**.

I have tried to implement the YOLOV3 on CPU however, it did not satisfy me about **FPS** values.
I want to implement it on **GPU**. So my question is **"Can I change some code of YOLOV3 GPU version** ?". What I mean by that is, when I open the **darknet** folder, I saw some files that were written in **C++**. I need to get the bounding box coordinates and modify some part of the codes. Is it possible to do that ?

In addition, I made some project with YOLOV3 about object detection on Python but as I said, I want to implement on GPU and also I am working on **Ubuntu 18.04.**

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special about the GPU code versus the CPU code.

You are asking about ML, so I'll take a tangent. Apologies if this is obvious. Compared to Python, C++ is compiled. So, you can't just expect to change some (C++) source and run again and obtain something different. This is true in most Python-based ML project, but not in C++.

You'll need to rebuild. Are you currently rebuilding the project?

You also don't make clear what changes you want to make. If it changes the network layers, you may have to retrain from scratch, instead of using pre-trained models. For most vision ML projects, the pretraining is very expensive in terms of computation. Consider this carefully.

Comment: If I was not clear I am sorry about that, and my main focus is trying to build a object detection project that takes another trained model and applying the two model as parameters (like weights) simultaneously. I can accomplish that in Python Language via **OpenCV libs** however, according to my searching on internet, **OpenCV's dnn modules** do not support **GPU acceleration** with Python. So I want to modify some code in **C++**.

Comment: So make sure you can build your project, then try changing the code. No reason you can't, as long as you have the right setup to build from source. (This will be more involved than you expect, it always is)

Comment: Actually what I also wanted to learn which file should I modify in the **darknet** ? Because I searched lots of source in the internet but could not find significant.